# Problem debugging in chrome after updating to angular 11

Tags: angular, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, angular11, chrome-debugging

After I updated my angular 9.1 application to angular 11:

- When debugging in one of the libraries chrome does not stop at my breakpoints.  Other libraries and app can be debugged like before.
- In the problematic library I also can not put breakpoints on if/for statements (breakpoints on these statements automatically go to the end of file). If I put breakpoint in the es2015.js file chrome puts the breakpoint on the correct place in the ts file but it is still not being hit.
  I did the upgrade using ng update first from angular 9.1 to angular 10 and than from angular 10 to angular 11.
  I already tried comparing the problematic library to the other libraries, and tried changing the library definitions and nothing helped.
  Thanks in advance for any ideas

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this/my following github issue
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20950

we had incorrect imports in our libraries. Imports came from `'import { xyz } from projects/src/...'` instead of `'import { xyz } from @lib/name'`

Found them with the regex: `^import([a-zA-Z\{\} ]*)'projects`